# Can I add a resource file programmatically?

Tags: c#

I am creating a license protector in c#.
I have two files ( `DATA.exe` & `Project1.exe` ) when I access the Project 1 it automatically reads the file DATA.exe as array of bytes, then decrypts it and loads it in memory***.
In order to avoid generating the data.exe file and ship it with the protected file, I wanted to embed the DATA.exe into the Project1.exe as a Binary Resource File and call it using :

```
  Byte[] encryptedfilebytes = Properties.Resources.crypteddata;
```

Now, I have only one file, when I click Project1.exe it would simply extract the DATA.exe from its resource, decrypt and load it into memory.

Here is the problem* :
The DATA.exe file is not always the same, it changes according to the input file and options selected when protecting the application. Is there some way to embed the DATA.exe file programmatically into the Project1.exe while protecting the input file we want to protect.

Comment: If you mean at project compile-time; then what you could do is to add a stub file to the project which is then overwritten during a pre-build event or indeed via a manually added MSBuild task in the project file.  Once added to the project, you can add it into your resource file and you can then have the file automatically update during a build.  If using source control, though you'd have to remember to check the file out before building if you do it this way.

Comment: I don't see any difference between having the bytes inside one .exe vs. having the bytes as a seperate .exe (or .dat or whatever)... can you explain a bit better why you have to pack it into the project1.exe? As this get's "linked/compiled" into the exe I think you would have to compile the file "on the go" - a feature that might be possible in future releases but right now I don't see a "not-hacking" way to do this - sorry

Comment: Is the file you want to add the resource to signed ?

Comment: Read the first line of my posted question. @CarstenKönig

Comment: @Yahia I think It is not signed, this is my project I created, how and why should i sign it?